# Matrix over commutative ring defines injective operator modulo Jacobson radical

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, commutative-algebra

Suppose $A\in \mathrm M_n(R)$ defines an injective linear operator modulo the Jacobson radical $J\vartriangleleft R$, i.e on $(R/J)^n)$. Does it follow that it defines an injective operator already on $R^n$?

Injectivity mod $J$ means $Au\in  JR^n\implies u\in JR^n$. In particular the kernel lies in $ JR^n$ so if the kernel had a complement, the complement would be everything whence the kernel would be zero...

Note that *surjectivity* mod $J$ means $\forall v\exists u\mid Au-v\in JR^n$ which gives $R^n=\mathrm{im}A+ JR^n$ which gives $\mathrm{im}A=R^n$ by Nakayama.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. For example, let $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]\big/\langle 2x,x^2\rangle$; for convenience denote the image of $x$ in $R$ as $c$. The maximal ideals of $R$ are the ideals of form $\langle p,c\rangle$ for some prime $p\in\mathbb{Z}$, so the Jacobson radical of $R$ is $\langle c\rangle$ and hence $R\big/J\cong\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, if $A$ is the $1\times 1$-matrix $(2)$, then $A$ acts injectively on $R\big/J$. But $A$ annihilates $c$ and hence does not act injectively on $R$.